# ElasticSearch : Configure delete_by_query,update_by_query to retry on version_conflicts

Tags: elasticsearch

update_by_query , delete_by_query are failing due to version conflicts
With below response.
Is it possible to configure delete_by_query , update_by_query to retry multiple times in such cases in Elasticsearch itself.

```
{
  "took": 18,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 7,
  "deleted": 2,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 5,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": [
    {

    }
  ]
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Yes, specify `?conflicts=proceed` in the URL

Comment: Thanks Val,
I tried giving "?conflicts=proceed" for _update_by_query.but looks like it is not retrying the operation,below was the response from ES 
Note: I am using AWS managed ES version : 6.2.3 

{
  "took": 37,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 2,
  "updated": 0,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 2,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": [
    
  ]
}
}

Comment: a version conflict means that the version you're trying to update has already been updated by another process, hence retrying will not serve any purpose. `conflicts=proceed` simply tells the process to ignore the conflict and continue updating other documents.